# IF Function in Excel not accepting commas

Tags: microsoft-excel

What am I doing wrong here, using the =IF in excel? I type `=IF(D7=D6,1,0)` see

[image]

Comment: The statement is correct. I tried it and works for me. Are you sure you use it correctly??

Comment: Are you currently focused on the cell with the formula in it?  When you press *Enter*, does the formula evaluate?

Comment: The screenshot looks like it has semi colons between the arguments instead of commas. Try semi colons.

Answer (score 6):

This is likely due to your region settings.  [This forum post](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/excel-wont-let-me-type-formula-using-commas-t3852174.html) mentions a similar problem.  If the comma is used when separating the whole and fractional parts of a number, it cannot be used to separate arguments in a formula.

To review how your computer interprets numbers, you can look at the "Regional and Language Options" in the Control Panel.  Look at the "Number" sample.  I'm using "English (United States)", so my number is "123,456,789**.**00".  (Note the decimal point separating the whole and fractional parts of the number.)

Looking at your screenshot, it looks like there are semicolons between the formula arguments in the tooltip, not commas.  Try using semicolons rather than commas to separate the arguments.

```
=IF(D7=D6;1;0)
```

Answer (score 4):

While [dangowans' answer](https://superuser.com/a/509752/117002) is a good workaround, it doesn't solve the problem for long-time users of Excel who are fluent in typing formulas using commas.

Switching to using a semi-colon after using Excel for over 20 years is not an option for me.

So here is how to "fix" what Microsoft has broken:

- Go to the `Region` settings (Start Menu.. type region and choose "Region", not "Region and language settings")
- Choose `Additional settings...`
- Update `Decimal symbol` to not be a comma - I use a decimal point (e.g. 1.3)
- Update `List separator` to be a comma.
- Apply
- Do the same thing on the `Currency` tab for the `Decimal symbol`

Excel will now accept formulas in the old way, and you will be able to use it like you always have.

---

References:

- [Semicolon in Excel formulas after upgrading to Windows 8 & Office 13](http://www.bw.co.za/?p=241)
- [Excel formulas requiring the use of ;](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/e06926cf-83d6-403b-9ae7-ac88283973c2/excel-formulas-requiring-the-use-of-?forum=excel)

Comment: +1 One must sometimes ask ones self: "Microsoft... WTF?" :P

Comment: Microsoft has bot "broken" anything. Excel has been using the separator from the locale settings for ages, probably always.

Comment: Not for "always" but definitely "for ages", yes, @GSerg. You might notice that you're commenting on a question that is almost 9 years old - this type of info was relatively new at that point in time.

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier It's less than 7 years, and I cannot agree this was a novelty in 2014. The first Excel that I used was 95 (1995), and it already used the locale separators.

Comment: @GSerg I said the "question" was old - from "Nov 23 '12". I'm glad that you and I have used Excel for so long. I'm glad that you did not have to experience that problem, perhaps the treatment of the ZA locale happened at a different time. Luckily for me, when the behaviour changed _for me_, I was able to solve it and get back to using the comma as I always had.

Answer (score -1):

It is in the Regional Settings in Windows 10. You can see in the List Separator Field, it is indicated a semicolon, just change it to comma.

Comment: This just duplicates the information in the existing answers.  Please don't post answers that do not contribute a new solution to the question.